# How to download tensorflow 1.14.0 on Pycharm?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

My assignment needs to use `tensorflow 1.14.0`, yet it reports:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow<1.15.0,>=1.14.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (from
versions: 2.2.0rc1, 2.2.0rc2, 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1,
2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3, 2.4.0rc4, 2.4.0)
```

It is the same result when I tried to use pip in the console. It seems that old version of `tensorflow` is not supported now, but my assignment requires that old version. Is there a way to download the older version? Or can the `tensorflow` 2 identify the code in `tensorflow 1.14.0`?

Comment: How exactly your assignment requires the old version? Is there a check for that? I'd assume, that the newest version should work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tensorflow Supported packages by anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow/files?sort=time&sort_order=desc)

Anaconda still seems to support tensorflow 1.14. You can download it from there.
It can also be seen in `conda search tensorflow`.

`conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.14` downloads the gpu version.

`conda install tensorflow==1.14` downloads the cpu version.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with Anaconda. Press **ctrl+alt+s** to open the project Settings/Preferences.
Press **Project:(Here is the name of project)** and go at **Python Interprenter**  . Click your python interprenter and change it to **anaconda**. After this go at Terminal and write **conda install tensorflow**.